# Selenium: Why am I getting an Error when trying to load a simple cookie?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
def save_cookies(driver, location):

    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(location, "wb"))


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver"
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
chrome.get("https://steamcommunity.com/login")
time.sleep(35)
save_cookies(chrome, "C:\\Users\\X\\cookies.txt")
chrome.quit()
```

Saving the cookies works perfectly, but when trying to load them

```
def load_cookies(driver, location, url=None):

    cookies = pickle.load(open(location, "rb"))
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    url = "https://google.com" if url is None else url
    driver.get(url)
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver"
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
load_cookies(chrome, "C:\\Users\\X\\cookies.txt")
chrome.get("https://steamcommunity.com/login")
```

I get this Error:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain: Cookie 'domain' mismatch

This might look sketchy, but all I'm trying to do is to automate trade accept.

Comment: Have you tried this in Firefox?

Comment: What line of code does the error correspond to?  Am I right to assume its in the `load_cookies` function?

Comment: @Jortega Yes, you are right. And no I didn't tried it in Firefox.

Comment: Could you let me know exactly what line the error is coming from?

Comment: yes i got similar problem with firefox, with this message: Cookies may only be set for the current domain (accounts.google.com). when checked the list of cookies i found that they have different domain names: '.google.com' and 'myaccount.google.com', the error is happening at the latter ones.